# Running multiple javascript functions with the same "this.value"

Tags: javascript

I am trying to run multiple functions and inserting the same value into those functions as I type in a specific text box that updates a search list as you type in it. This works fine if I stick to just one function, however if I try and include multiple functions to be run onclick of the search button I attached and separate these out into a placeholder function, it does not work. I cannot for the life of me figure out what I am doing wrong here and feel like this isn't covered substantially anywhere, or I am off course on best practice here?

```js
function updateText(text) {
  var searchValue = document.getElementById("testID").value;
  document.getElementById("textTestID").setAttribute("value", searchValue);
}

function functionRunner() {
  function1('this.value');
  function2('this.value');
  function3('this.value');
}
```

```html
<form autocomplete="off">
  <div class="autocomplete">
    <input id="testID" type="text" placeholder="Search..." onchange="updateTextAutofill();" onkeyup="updateText(this.value);">
  </div>
  <button id="textTestID" onclick="functionRunner('this.value');" class="link"><img src="/icons/goArrow.png" style="height:34px; width:34px;"></button>
</form>
```

Comment: Don't use a string `'this.value'`, but just the property reference `this.value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already reading the input value in your `updateText` function with this

`var searchValue = document.getElementById("testID").value;`

so you dont need to pass anything to `updateText`.

Regarding the `functionRunner`, just read the value at the beginning and then pass it to the other functions:

```js
    function updateText() {
      var searchValue = document.getElementById("testID").value;
      document.getElementById("textTestID").setAttribute("value", searchValue);
    }

    function functionRunner() {
      var searchValue = document.getElementById("testID").value;

      function1(searchValue);
      function2(searchValue);
      function3(searchValue);
    }
```

```html
<form autocomplete="off">
  <div class="autocomplete">
    <input id="testID" type="text" placeholder="Search..." onchange="updateTextAutofill();" onkeyup="updateText();">
  </div>
  <button id="textTestID" onclick="functionRunner();" class="link"><img src="/icons/goArrow.png" style="height:34px; width:34px;"></button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

GiampaoloGabba's is a better answer, but if you wanted to keep your code the same as you have it, then:

```
onclick="functionRunner(this.value)"

function functionRunner(searchValue) {
  function1(searchValue);
  function2(searchValue);
  function3(searchValue);
}
```

You don't need the '' around `this.value` etc... And you need to receive the value into the funtion with `functionRunner(searchValue)`